# Testing iPad applications

Tags: ipad, hardware, low-memory

Bit of a hardware question here. I am developing iPad applications for a client and am finding that when I send over beta versions for the client to test, he is finding many more crashes on his devices than I am seeing. A lot of these crashes are 'low memory crashes' which I simply am not seeing/able to reproduce.

Am wondering what differences between the 2 devices there may be so that we can work out if it is a hardware issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of the client's configuration/environment matches your environment. Eg: Outlook Exchange Sync, MobileMe sync. In my Contacts application these caused a lot of crashes because of these.

If possible add more logs and get the logs from console of the client device and verify.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your client has more stuff running at the same time. Or your own app is background-enabled and is getting killed from time to time...

Always test your own code with the Simulator - it has a feature that allows you to simulate low memory warnings.